# Installed Node.js successfully! Oh but why is this code not rendering?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The output is

```
{$questions[i]}
```

and it is not rendering my first question!

this is the code:

```
var questions = [
  "What is your name?",
  "What is your favorite fruit?",
  "What is the meaning of life?"
];
var answers = [];

function ask(i){
    process.stdout.write(`\n\n {$questions[i]} \n\n `);
    process.stdout.write(" > ");
}

ask(0);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The dollar sign is in the wrong place.

Comment: And advise to avoid future problems, write strings inside single quotes `'`.

Comment: @Dez that's not relevant at all to template literals

Comment: Btw, what node.js version do you use? Template strings were added in Node.js v4.0.0.

Comment: I misread the question and started reading about `Writable#cork()` and `Writable#uncork()` because I assumed it was some sort of buffering issue with directly using `process.stdout.write()`... I will say it certainly helps to read more thoroughly before jumping to conclusions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close! A template literal syntax is `${}`, not `{$}`. So what you're looking for is:

This is easily confused because most front end templating engines use curly braces as wrappers {...}.

```
process.stdout.write(`\n\n ${questions[i]} \n\n `);
```

Comment: @RamonaDDeveloper if it answered your question, considering marking it as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Visit the [help] for more information, and welcome to Stack Overflow!